# .Net Core 5.0 - Adding Role to users at registration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

Sorry for an obvious question but I'm net to .Net Core.
I'm working on a new project that was created using Visual Studio on Mac with "Individual Authentication".

I want to assign Role to user right at the registration process (depending on their choice - dropdown option). I read many tutorials and watched many videos, but I cannot understand what's the right way to do it.
In many videos I was guided to create a project without Authentication and implement it manually including sign up and sign in.

I'm confused because I'm getting this functionality right away by creating a new project with Authentication.
But in my project I don't have access to files like "RegistrationController" or "Sign Up" View.

My questions:

1. Should I use "Individual Authentication"?
2. How to assign Role to user at the registration?
3. How to edit Sign up page (which is currently hidden in my VisualStudio, despite that I can register new users) to add dropdown.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Should I use "Individual Authentication"?

Yes, Individual User Accounts

> 2. How to assign Role to user at the registration?

example:
_userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin")
NB: the role has to have already been added to the database using the role manager.

> 3. How to edit Sign up page (which is currently hidden in my VisualStudio, despite that I can register new users) to add dropdown.

To update your view you need to right-click on your project and Select Add> New Scaffolded Item > Identity. Your view will be in Area section and you can make the needed changes.

> I also recommend looking over the documentation if you haven't already
> done so:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Hope this hepls.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately the steps didn't work on VisualStudio on Mac, but the article was helpful. Thanks again!